# Open in new tab

Tags: html

How can I get the URL below to open in a new tab? My config.php file automatically fills in the 'BASE_PATH' and it opens successfully, but I can't seem to get it to open in a new tab.

An assistance would be appreciated.

```
if(!empty($id))
    $link = "<a class='text-success' href='" . BASE_PATH . "quiz-result.php?uuid=" . $id . "'>View Result</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the target="_blank" attribute. Like this:

```
if(!empty($id))
  $link = "<a class='text-success' target='_blank' href='".BASE_PATH."quiz-result.php?uuid=".$id."'>View Result</a>";
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Chip,....I can't post another question until 90 minutes have passed.....Can you tell me how to make an entire php website available offline please.....I tried putting all the php files into a manifest.appcache....but it will only work when I add one .php.......How to make atleast 20 php files in a website available offline ?

Comment: You would need to install a local web server like XAMP, or WAMP. Then you could serve the php files on your local system.

Comment: Chip....My website is already hosted online.....are there any other solutions you can think of ?.....I'm willing to try anything

Comment: Your php code must be run. You need a web server to serve the code. It's not like pure html files, which you can just visit in your browser when they are on your computer.